# Para que serve isso? requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Tags: android

Estava estudando uma webservice para o android consumir e me deparei com isso::

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.loginuser);

    }
```

Por que eu deveria utilizar
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 ?

Answer (score 1):

Para remover a status bar do android.
Alguns aplicativos tipo games fazem isso pra ficar em tela cheia.
Ou pra fazer a slash screen com o logo sozinho na tela.

Answer (score 1):

Eu costumo usar isso quando quero crio um AlertDialog personalizado. Aí, isso esse código para remover aquela barra de título. Pois, se não adiciono esse código, e barra de título fica com o fundo branco.